# compactness of the operator $Tx (t) = t x(t)$ ($0< t < 1 $)

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Is the operator $T$ defined by $Tx (t) = t x(t)$ ($0< t < 1 $) compact in $L^2(0,1)$?

It is conjectured that it is indeed compact. But I cannot find a proof. Can anyone give one?

This is a problem in the book by Friedman.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true.

Take the sequence $u_n = \chi_{(1-\frac1n,1)}\sqrt n$ with $\|u_n\|_{L^2}=1$. Then
$$
\|Tu_n\|_{L^2}^2 = n \int_{(1-\frac1n,1)} t^2 dt = \frac n3( 1 - (1-\frac1n)^3) = 1-\frac1n + \frac1{3n^2} \to1,
$$
and $(Tu_n)(t) \to 0$  almost everywhere. Hence $(Tu_n)$ cannot have a converging subsequence in $L^2$, since for strongly converging sequences the $L^2$-limit and the pointwise limit coincide.

Comment: for strongly converging sequences the L2-limit and the pointwise limit coincide. Is it still true for other $ L^p$ spaces?

Comment: yes, for all of them